# Каждые 2 секунды приходит json-ответ от сервера. Как подвесить событие на изменение значения?

Tags: javascript, ajax

У меня два вопроса, связанные между собой:
1) Есть ли специальные события, которые реагируют на изменение значения переменной?
2) К примеру есть следующий код:

```
if(xhr.status == 200){
    let jsonic = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
}
```

Как можно сравнить одну и ту же переменную `jsonic` с разницей в 2 секунды?

Comment: Погоди ка, а xhr это разве не запрос клиент-сервер? т.е. вы каждые 2 секунды делаете запрос? Или как это у вас происходит, можете пояснить?

Comment: @Анатолий Шевелев, пожалуйста! 
`function show_files(){
 let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'handler-list.php');
 xhr.send();
 
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState != 4){
   return; 
  }
  if(xhr.status == 200){
    list.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    list.style.border = "";
  }
  else{
   list.style.border = "1px solid red";
   list.innerHTML = "Не удалось связаться с сервером!";
  }
 }
}

function start(){
 id = setInterval("show_files()", 2000);
 return id;
}

list.onload = start();`

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Есть ли специальные события, которые реагируют на изменение
>   значения переменной?

Специального события нет, но вы можете написать функции getter/setter. В `setter` которых будет либо генерироваться событие, либо выполняться нужный код.
Это сильно улучшит архитектуру, если таких переменных станет больше.

```js
var jsonic = {
  _val: 0,
  set value(val) {
    this._val = val;
     
     // Выполняем нужный код. Опционально можно генерировать событие, зависит от закладываемой архитектуры взаимодействия
     alert( val );
  },
  get value() {
    return this._val;
  }
};

jsonic.value = 123;
console.log( jsonic.value );
```

Если необходимо что-то делать только при изменении значения, можно немного модифицировать код:

```js
var jsonic = {
  _val: 0, 
  set value(val) {
    if( this._val == val ) {
      return false;
    };
    this._val = val;

     // Выполняем нужный код. Опционально можно генерировать событие, зависит от закладываемой архитектуры взаимодействия
     alert( val );
  },
  get value() {
    return this._val;
  }
};

jsonic.value = 123;
console.log( jsonic.value );

// Второго alert не будет
jsonic.value = 123;
```

Comment: Тут возникает другой вопрос: как вернуть значение `xhr.response`?

Comment: Возможно неверно вас понял, но `jsonic.value = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldJsonicText;
var jsonicText;

setInterval(function() {
  if (oldJsonicText != jsonicText) {
    ...
    oldJsonicText = jsonicText;
  }
}, 2000);

if(xhr.status == 200){
    if (jsonicText != xhr.responseText) {
      ...
      jsonicText = xhr.responseText;
    }
    let jsonic = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Оптимизация хромает

Comment: @Igor, что-то не сведу свой код с вашим. Мне нужно сделать так. При первом ответе сервера применить `list.innerText = jsonic`. Через 2 секунды, если следующий ответ сервера отличается от предыдущего, обновить `list.innerHTML`, если не отличается - оставить как есть